# NoMethodError: undefined method class_inheritable_accessor’ for PDF::Toolkit:Class`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

Hi I'm trying to read a pfd in RoR 3.2.8, for that I did:

```
gem install pdf-toolkit
```

I added the gem to the Gemfile: `gem "pdf-toolkit", "0.5.0"`

After i did a bundle install and everything was working, bur now when I try to execute my program I get this error: `NoMethodError: undefined method class_inheritable_accessor’ for PDF::Toolkit:Class`

I was looking for a solution, but unfortunately I couldn’t solve it, any ideas? Thanks!

Here is a pice of my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'pdf/toolkit'

class Terminations
  def initialize
    @seperator = " "
    #@extract_file = "/uploads/Test and rates.pdf"
  end
..
...
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method class_inheritable_accessor was [removed from ActiveSupport in Rails 3.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9cafc28874a681082f9f7e1e445db91f195a25ae). The version of pdf-toolkit you are attempting to use was released in 2006 and it doesn't look like it's even being maintained anymore. There is a [1.0 release candidate](https://rubygems.org/gems/pdf-toolkit/versions/1.0.0.rc1) that was published in Feb. 2012 that you could try, but I wouldn't recommend depending on an abandoned gem for production use. The [github README](https://github.com/blambeau/pdf-toolkit) says the following:

> This is a prerelease 1.0.0.rc1 version on an almost abandonned
>   project. The main difference (broken API) with the 0.5.0 branch is
>   that support for ActiveRecord has been entirely removed (mostly
>   because the implementation was ugly so far). If you use pdf-toolkit
>   and would like activerecord to be included in 1.0.0, please just tell
>   us and we'll add it. If you upgrade from 0.5.0 to 1.0.0.rc1 and
>   something else goes wrong, please report the issue on github.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm new in ruby on rails and I didn't know about that, now that problem is solved but I have a new one: Error invoking PDFTK in this line: my_pdf = PDF::Toolkit.open(path), any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @Anna I'd recommend opening a new Stack Overflow question and posting the entire stacktrace. It will be easier for someone to comment and help you that way.

Comment: add to your gemfile: gem "pdf-toolkit", "~> 1.0.0.rc1"